# Selenium unique element not returned by span text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On a web page, this element is the only one containing the exact text 'Volgende stap':

```
<span class="b-button--label ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="arrowDirection === 'right'">Volgende stap</span>
```

But when I try to select (a list of) the elements containing these words using xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Volgende')]")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[.='Volgende stap']")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Volgende stap']")
```

I keep getting an empty list (or `element not found` in case of `find_element` instead of `find_elements`).

This is the script leading to the html page I'm working on:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.greetz.nl/kaarten/verjaardag/man")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='/kaart/detail/greetz-verjaardagskaart---abracadabra/1142778148']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Kaart bewerken']"))).click()
```

Comment: so if I go to that page and manually click on `/kaart/detail/greetz-verjaardagskaart---abracadabra/1142778148` and search for `Volgende` on either visible page, or page source, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML the desired element with text as **Volgende stap** is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.personalize--frame[src='//www.greetz.nl/editor/desktop.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.b-button--label.ng-binding.ng-scope[ng-if*='right'][]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='personalize--frame' and @src='//www.greetz.nl/editor/desktop.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='b-button--label ng-binding ng-scope' and contains(text(),'Volgende')]"))).click()
    ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: I see, so it was because of an Iframe. Thanks for the explanation and link to more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's in an iframe. Switch to it first, then try and find via text:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame.personalize--frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```